# How to solve this using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

You are given a vector of test scores called tests, and wish to normalize these scores by computing a new vector, normTests, which will contain the test scores on a linear scale from 0 to 100. A zero will still correspond to zero, and the highest test score will correspond to 100. For example, if the highest score in the original data was 50, then all scores would be doubled.

Comment: Why is this tagged `[javascript]` if your question mentions MATLAB? Also, is this a homework question? (stackoverflow.com is not for getting people to do your homework for you)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know MATLAB very well, but what you want to do is something like

```
normTests = (tests / max(tests))*100
```

Dividing the test scores by the maximum will produce a linear scale between 0 and 1, multiplying by 100 brings it back to 0 to 100

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the vector by 100/x, where x is the maximum value in the vector.